# android material design button bug

Tags: android

Like the picture, I set a dark green color, but the light green background appears.
This is the only thing I've set up.
Button's background was set to the colorPrimary of the theme.
So when I changed Button to Image Button, it came out right.
As a result of the test, it seems that the problem is occurring in material design 1.2.1 or higher.
I have to use Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar, so I can't change Theme.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in material design, and found solution adding `app:backgroundTint`.